# how to set an HTML border like this without using table?

Tags: html, border

I want to set an inside border on the "Terms and Conditions" header like shown [Here](http://www.teabungalow.in/termsconditions.htm)
And I don't want to use a table. Is there any way around this?
Please help.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+columns+with+borders

Comment: Do you mean the border with the fancy corners?

Comment: Can you edit your post and give us an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You may modify/amend the styles as per your requirement but I have given you a basic approach.

```
.header{background:#fff; padding:10px;}
.inner-header{border:1px solid grey;}


<div class="header">
     <div class="inner-header">
         This one will have the border
     </div>
</div>
```